# First letter every word of header tag in CSS little bigger

Tags: css

I want first letter of all words to be little bigger than rest

```css
h1 {
  color: #1c1c1d;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: -2px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #082b34;
}

h1::first-letter {
  font-size: 125%;
}
```

```html
<h1> WELCOME TO HOMEPAGE </h1>
```

But this only increasing the 'W' in WELCOME.
If possible with use of `<span>`

Comment: This is not at all a duplicate of the above link

Comment: Duplicated link makes no sense.

Comment: @SilverSurfer can you explain how the duplicate make no sense? The below answer made each word in a span then applied first letter and the duplicate provided a better solution by directly putting each first letter in a span.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`first-letter` works only for block elements so remove `display:inline;` and you are good to go.

```css
h1 {
  color: #1c1c1d;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: -2px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #082b34;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
}

span::first-letter {
  font-size: 200%;
  color: #eb632d;
}
```

```html
<h1> <span>WELCOME</span> <span>TO</span> <span>HOMEPAGE</span> </h1>
```

Comment: I want 'T' n TO, and 'H' in HOMPAGE just like the 'W' In WELCOME in the same line

Comment: @InfraDBA i have updated the code for you

Comment: Superb !! Thats what I wanted